# multi targeting in command line compiler (csc.exe)

Tags: .net

My question is simple: How can I do multi-targeting in command line compiler (csc.exe), especially to .Net 4 **Client Profile**?

---

edit: Ok, Is my question too simple?

The compiler, targeting to .net 4.5, is `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`. When I run `csc source.cs`, the output is targeting to .net 4.5.

I want to target to .net 4 client profile in command line compiler(csc.exe), such as `csc /targetFramework="v4.0;Profile=Client" source.cs`. (Of course, there's no option `/targetFramework`...)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you not configure your .csproj appropriately and use msbuild?

Comment: @JaimeTorres Humm.. then could you tell me how to make .csproj in "runtime"? I need to compile in runtime, such as `Process.Start("csc source.cs")` (and I don't know how to write msbuild project file (syntax, etc..). I'll appreciate your help if you can tell me howto..)

Comment: @ikh What do you mean in "runtime"?  Are you generating entire applications dynamically and then compiling them?  If so, you would simply have to use a template for a .csproj file and create it by hand.  It's a simple XML file, so it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: You should try creating a .csproj file by using Visual Studio (use Express if you have to). The .csproj should target the Framework version you want. Turn on verbose logging for builds in Tools->Options. Then build the .csproj file and look at the output to see which switches it passes to csc.exe. Those will be the switches you need to use "in runtime".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to compile at runtime, then you should consider the [providers in System.CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which allow compilation without invoking a separate process.

To answer your original question, if you turn the MSBuild verbosity to Detailed in Visual Studio (Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run) and build a project targeted at client profile, you will see this in the build output:

`Csc.exe (stuff...) Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\...\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"`

The path in quotes is actually a generated temp file, containing:

`[assembly: TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile")]`

So, you should be able to use that attribute in your own code if you are invoking csc directly.

Comment: What I said, "compile at runtime", is just such as `Process.Start("csc")`.. anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TargetFramework can be configured in the Project file only and can't be passed as a switch to CSC.exe, see settings for **TargetFrameworkVersion** and **TargetFrameworkProfile** in below example

So the only way to dynamically set is to modify the project file with below setting and compile with csc.exe if you want to set **Client Profile**

Targetting .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A5F58561-47CA-482A-83E0-1D43C312B0A7}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApplication1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Targetting .NET Framework 4.0

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A5F58561-47CA-482A-83E0-1D43C312B0A7}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConsoleApplication1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile></TargetFrameworkProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```